# Group by causing datagrid to fail

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I have a c# application whose GUI has datagrid which is being populated at the moment with the following sql

```
      UPDATE    mi
      SET       mi.ClientName = c.ClientName
      FROM      generic.MasterInventory mi INNER JOIN
                generic.Client c ON mi.FK_Client = c.PK_Client
      SELECT DISTINCT 
                ClientName, FundName, PK_MasterInventory, FK_Fund, FK_Client, ISIN,  Status, ShareCurrency, PriceFrequency, ClassCode, Simulation, Hedged, 
                                              FundCurrency, [Type]                                                             FROM         generic.MasterInventory
```

However I am having trouble removing the duplicate records . I have tried using groupby

```
      UPDATE    mi
      SET       mi.ClientName = c.ClientName
      FROM      generic.MasterInventory mi INNER JOIN
                generic.Client c ON mi.FK_Client = c.PK_Client
      SELECT DISTINCT 
                ClientName, FundName, PK_MasterInventory, FK_Fund, FK_Client, ISIN,  Status, ShareCurrency, PriceFrequency, ClassCode, Simulation, Hedged, 
                                              FundCurrency, [Type]                                                               FROM         generic.MasterInventory
       GROUP BY ClientName
```

However doing this results in an empty datagrid ...Does anyone know why this is/ a workaround ?

Running Group by in Query builder gives this error message

```
      Column generic.masterInventory.FundName is invalid 
      in the select list because it is not contained in 
      either an aggregate function or the group by clause
```

Comment: You need to group by any column that is not part of an aggregate function. But you don't even use an aggregate function. So why grouping at all?

Comment: When you use Group By, you have to use also aggregation functions  ( Sum, Count ... ) better take a look at Group By syntax.

Comment: @Ralf AdelKhayata  ah ok , was using group by as a few similar topics suggested it , is there a similar way then I can code to prevent duplicate values in the fund or maybe the client column ?

Comment: Duplicate what? Just ClientName or the rest of the fields? If just ClientName, what do you want to do with non-duplicated rest of the fields?

Comment: Client name and fund name keep throwing duplicate values , I want to just take the first instance of whatever values are duplicating